# How to find a file that render html of a function?

Tags: magento-1.9, core

How to find a file in Magento Core that render `getPayementHtml()` function (*Admin Default Template*)?

[image: function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPaymentHtml()` method render from

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/Info.php

And In `Info.php` file getPaymentHtml return `$this->getChildHtml('order_payment')`.

`order_payment` render from

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Payment.php

hope this is help to you many thanks.